# Log Analytics Query specific disk (LUN)

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-log-analytics-workspace

Hi I'm trying to query a specific disk Throughput but cannot find the specific value that has to be input to get the throughput chart from that specific disk.  Is that even possible?

This is what I have until now:

```
Perf
 | where ObjectName == "LogicalDisk"
 | where CounterName == "Disk Bytes/sec"
 | where Computer contains "computername"
 | summarize ThroughputInMBs = (max(CounterValue)/1024/1024) by Computer, bin(TimeGenerated, 5m)
 | render timechart
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the below line in your query to filter the specific VM.

```sql
| where Computer == "<Your Disk Name>"
```

Final Query to fetch specific Disk details in a Log Analytic Workspace

```sql
Perf
 | where Computer == "VM1"
 | where ObjectName == "LogicalDisk"
 | where CounterName == "Disk Bytes/sec"
 | summarize ThroughputInMBs = (avg(CounterValue)/1024/1024) by Computer, bin(TimeGenerated, 5m)
 | render timechart
```

#### Result

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion.  I've tried you're suggesting by putting the disk name in the first line but now is not showing results.  In you're example VM1 is your disk name?

Comment: yes, vm1 is my deskname

Comment: oh ok, in my side when I put the disk name it doesn't bring data.  Its weird

Comment: hi @DelliganeshS-MT  I see that in you're test it work since your disk is 'VM1' and it bring you back data but in my case it did not work with disk name from the azure portal and disk name from the OS none work.  I think I should mark it as fix, right?

Comment: yes, you can try with some other workspace.